# C# IQueryable - TakeLast(__p_0)' could not be translated Error

Tags: c#, linq

My private get all method

```
    private IQueryable<Category> getAll()
        => _unitOfWork.CategoryRepo
               .GetAll()
               .Include(x => x.CategoryDetails)
               .Include(x => x.Categories)
               .ThenInclude(x => x.CategoryDetails);
```

This is what i tried:

```
await getAll().OrderBy(x => x.Id).TakeLast(1000).ToListAsync()
```

Error (Same error in .net 6 and 3.1):

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Category>()
    .Include(x => x.CategoryDetails)
    .Include(x => x.Categories)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.CategoryDetails)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .TakeLast(__p_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: It is not related to .Net version. Last() is not something that could be translated to underlying data source's dialect. Instead OrderByDescending and Take(1000). TakeLast() applies to IEnumerable, not IQueryable. You can use TakeLast() if you first use, say AsEnumerable(). It wouldn't be feasible though, OrderByDescending and Take() is a better approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well `TakeLast` can't be translated to SQL, but why you use `TakeLast` at all?

```
await getAll().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(1000).ToListAsync()
```

So order in the desired way and then use `Take` instead of `TakeLast`.